# Split string from BeautifulSoup output in a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following output from my code

Code: `text = soup.get_text()`

Output:

```
Article Title

    Some text: Text blurb.

More blurb.

Even more blurb. 

Some more blurb. 





Second Article Title

Some text: Text blurb.

More blurb.

Even more blurb. 

Some more blurb.
```

Next, when I do `test = text.splitlines()`, the output changes to

```
u'Article Title', u'', u'Some text',u'Text blurb',u'More blurb',u'Even more blurb',u'Some more blurb',, u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',u'Second Article Title', u'', u'Some text:',u'Text blurb',u'More blurb',u'Even more blurb',u'Some more blurb',, u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
```

I'd like to split the string using `u'', u'', u'', u'', u''` so that I can then individually parse out the lines. I'd have liked to use the tags but their structure makes it difficult to use.

How do I perform the split? I have tried:

```
result = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(test,lambda x:x=="u''") if not k]
print result
```

and

```
for item in test:
    arr = re.split("u'', u'', u'', u'', u''",item, flags=re.UNICODE)
    print arr
```

but they don't give me the desired output.

Comment: Do you want to split on `5 * '\n'`?

Comment: Go ahead and post the html structure, I'm curious about if there's maybe an easier way you're missing

Comment: I just saw your response to my other question. I was trying the alternative approach. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: the `u` is mark the string format is Unicode and only add when print, you can't use as the string.split() parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at your text, you want to split by repeated newlines `\n` from

```
text
>> 'Article Title\n\n    Some text: Text blurb.\n\nMore blurb.\n\nEven more blurb. \n\nSome more blurb. \n\n\n\n\n\nSecond Article Title\n\nSome text: Text blurb.\n\nMore blurb.\n\nEven more blurb. \n\nSome more blurb. '
```

You can then just use define a parameter for `text.split('\n\n\n\n\n')`, if you don't add a parameter, Python simply splits by whitespaces. After your first split, you can then split your other elements by `\n\n`.

```
[i.split('\n\n') for i in text.split('\n\n\n\n\n')]

>>[['Article Title',
  '    Some text: Text blurb.',
  'More blurb.',
  'Even more blurb. ',
  'Some more blurb. '],
 ['\nSecond Article Title',
  'Some text: Text blurb.',
  'More blurb.',
  'Even more blurb. ',
  'Some more blurb. ']]
```